# Print lines not containg a period linux

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a file with thousands of rows. I want to print the rows which do not contain a period.

```
awk '{print$2}' file.txt | head
```

I have used this to print the column I am interested in, column 2 (The file only has two columns). 
I have removed the head and then did

```
awk '{print$2}' file.txt | grep -v "." | head
```

But I only get blank lines not any actual values which is expected, I think it has included the spaces between the rows but I am not sure.

Is there an alternative command?

As suggested by Jim, I did-

```
awk '{print$2}' file.txt | grep -v "\." | head
```

However the number of lines is greater than before, is this expected? Also, my output is a list of numbers but with spaces in between them (Vertical), is this normal?

file.txt example below-

```
120.4 3
270.3 7.9
400.8 3.9

200.2 4
100.2 8.7
300.2 3.4

102.3 6
49.0 2.3
38.0 1.2
```

So the expected (and correct) output would be 3 lines, as there is 3 values in column 2 without the period:

```
$ awk '{print$2}' file.txt | grep -v "\." | head
3
4
6
```

However, when running the code as above, I instead get 5, which is also counting the spaces between the rows I think:

```
$ awk '{print$2}' file.txt | grep -v "\." | head
3

4 

6
```

Comment: Can you create a self-contained test case? I.e. include a short `file.txt`, along with the output you get and the output you expected? (Make sure to run on that new test case and not on your original file)

Comment: Not sure if I did this correctly but I put it in as code as was not sure how to include the .txt file itself, hope thats okay

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the last paragraph, do you want the lines themselves, or just their count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seldom need to use `grep` if you're already using `awk`

This would print the second column on each line where that second column doesn't contain a dot:

```
awk '$2 !~ /\./ {print $2}'
```

But you also wanted to skip empty lines, or perhaps ones where the second column is not empty. So just test for that, too:

```
awk '$2 != "" && $2 !~ /\./ {print $2}'
```

<sub>(A more amusing version would be `awk '$2 ~ /./ && $2 !~ /\./ {print $2}'` )</sub>

---

As you said, `grep -v "."` gives you only blank lines. That's because the dot means "any character", and with `-v`, the only lines printed are those that don't contain, well, any characters.

Answer (score 0):

grep is interpreting the dot as a regex metacharacter (the dot will match any single character).  Try escaping it with a backslash:

```
awk '{print$2}' file.txt | grep -v "\." | head
```

Comment: I just did this and it appeared to work. However the output is a list of the numbers going down but with spaces in between them? Not sure why they are there. Plus, the total value is higher than it was without the backslash

Comment: The `grep -v` removes any lines which contain a full stop.  Your Awk command is printing empty lines and those do not contain a full stop, so those are being printed, too.  But like it says in ilkkachu's answer, the proper solution is really to put it all in Awk.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you can try this sed

```
sed ':A;N;${s/.*/&\n/};/\n$/!bA;s/\n/ /g;s/\([^ ]*\.[^ ]* \)//g' file.txt

output
3 
4 
6
```